# Connectionstring that an pod should use to connect to an postgresql pod in same cluster?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, npgsql

I am currently working on a application which will be running in a kubernetes pod. It is supposed to connect to a postgressql pod, that is ran within the same cluster.

but I can for some reason not deduce what the connection string should be

I for now defined the postgressql deployment as such:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:10.4
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgredb
      volumes:
        - name: postgredb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pv-claim   

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres-service
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  ports:
   - port: 5432
     targetPort: 5432 
  selector:
   app: postgres
```

but for a connection string

```
            x.UseNpgsql("Host=postgres-service:5432;Database=postgres;Username=postgres;Password=postgres"));
```

Which does not seem to work?

Something as simple as

```
using System;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

    namespace pingMe
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
                Ping ping = new Ping();
                PingReply pingresult = ping.Send("postgres-service.default.svc.cluster.local");
                if (pingresult.Status.ToString() == "Success")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("I can reach");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

resolve into this:

within the cluster triggers an error

```
    System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException: An exception occurred during a Ping request.
 ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (00000005, 0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.GetAddressAndSend(String hostNameOrAddress, Int32 timeout, Byte[] buffer, PingOptions options)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.GetAddressAndSend(String hostNameOrAddress, Int32 timeout, Byte[] buffer, PingOptions options)
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send(String hostNameOrAddress, Int32 timeout, Byte[] buffer, PingOptions options)
   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.Send(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at API.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, SchemaContext schemaContext) in /src/API/Startup.cs:line 42
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.b__2(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Unhandled exception. System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException: An exception occurred during a Ping request.
```

Kubernetes service

```
kubectl get svc postgres-service
NAME               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
postgres-service   ClusterIP   10.106.91.9   <none>        5432/TCP   74m
```

Dockerfile:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["pingMe/pingMe.csproj", "pingMe/"]
RUN dotnet restore "pingMe/pingMe.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/pingMe"
RUN dotnet build "pingMe.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "pingMe.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "pingMe.dll"]
```

Local pod:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: local-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: local-pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: local-deployment
        image: api:dev5
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /WeatherForecast
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 3
          periodSeconds: 3
```

Comment: where do you run ping from? your terminal? inside a pod? please also provide the output of `kubectl get svc postgres-service`

Comment: I run the ping from C# application, during startup as the first thing. The application exposes port 80,443,5432 @morgwai

Comment: try to focus: where is the c# app being executed? from your visual studio? from your terminal? from a kubernetes pod?

Comment: local pod is the pod that runs the C# api which during startup pings the ip address as the first thing

Comment: ah, I can see the problem now: the ping should be made to `postgres-service.default.svc.cluster.local`, not `postgres-service.default.svc.cluster.local:5432`. you make pings to a host, not to a specific port.

Comment: still same output @morgwai

Comment: I can still see 5432 at least in the question... also did your rebuild and re-pushed your image?

Comment: @morgwai updated with the actual dummy code I am running in the pod

Comment: please try to ping just `postgres-service.default.svc` your cluster may have different domain configured. if this doesn't help, I don't have more ideas at the moment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand why.. But all my asp. Net core containerized application was not able to resolve the service name..

These had to be resolved in a separate step using 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostname?view=netframework-4.8
, and then passed as an ip address, resolved from the prior step..

I based this upon how nslookup responded, it initially fails as the dns record is not cached, and then resolves the host name as this can be found via broadcast.

I guess since the initial dns lookup fails, it triggers and exception which mine kept failing at...

Comment: I'm glad you found your bug and fixed it!! Please consider upvoting the answers you find useful to troubleshooting process, so others in the community can be helped when facing similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: `postgres-service.default.svc`

see the [explanation in the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services): `default` is your namespace name and cluster domain part can be omitted.

Comment: so you suggest that I use to  `postgres-service.default.svc:5432`

I tried pinging it -  i seem to get `name or service not known`?

Comment: @kafka where do you ping it from? your local terminal? it won't work of course: this name is resolved to cluster internal ip

Comment: or postgres-service.default.svc.cluster.local

Comment: I am running the application as an pod inside the cluster - So i am very surprised that I am able to ping it or connect to it within...

Comment: `postgres-service.default.svc.cluster.local `is the same as `postgres-service.default.svc`: as i wrote cluster domain can be omitted

Comment: Updated the question...  with stacktrace

Comment: looks like the kubernetes pod is unable to resolve the service name? i find it a bit weird though

Answer (score 0):

Does the /etc/resolv.conf file inside the pod has IP of coredns pod? It should look like below:

```
u@pod$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.0.0.10 # IP of core dns pod
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local example.com
options ndots:5
```

Also check if you are able to lookup any other service

```
nslookup kubernetes.default.svc
```

Check this [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/) on how to debug issues with services in kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

I've read all answers and comments, let's start over so we can have a new point of view.

> I am currently working on a application which will be running in a kubernetes pod. It is supposed to connect to a PostgreSql pod, that is ran within the same cluster.

In order to help you, we need to test each step of your environment separately.

First, one clarification:

- **Services does not accept ping**, to test the service you have to test the port of the application which is exposed. It's designed this way.

---

### Step 1 - We need to ensure the PostgreSQL service is functioning properly.

*This is my deployed PostgreSQL:*

```sh
$ kubectl get all 
NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/postgresql-0   1/1     Running   0          99m

NAME                          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/postgresql            ClusterIP   10.0.8.179   <none>        5432/TCP   99m
service/postgresql-headless   ClusterIP   None         <none>        5432/TCP   99m
service/kubernetes            ClusterIP   10.0.0.1     <none>        443/TCP    8d

NAME                          READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/postgresql   1/1     99m
```

- **Section A -** Run a `postgresql-client` interactive shell pod:

```
$ kubectl run postgresql-client --rm --tty -i --restart='Never' \
--namespace default \
--image docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:11.6.0-debian-10-r0 \
--env="PGPASSWORD=postgres" \
--command -- psql --host postgres \
-U postgres -d postgres -p 5432
```

If credentials are correct, You will see `postgres=#`. Try running some a command like `\du`:

```
postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

IF: it works! Go to **Step 2**.

**IF NOT:**

- **Section B -** Test manually with `postgresql-client`.

Start a single execution pod of a Ubuntu shell:

`kubectl run -i --tty --rm --image ubuntu test-shell -- /bin/bash`

Then install the postgresql client and nslookup:

`apt update && apt install postgresql-client -y && apt install dnsutils -y`

Run a `nslookup` to the service:

```
root@test-shell-845c969686-h9gz2:/# nslookup postgresql
Server:         10.0.0.10
Address:        10.0.0.10#53

Name:   postgresql.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.0.8.179
```

*As you can see, as we are working in the same **cluster** and **namespace**, any calls made to kneeling-scorpion-postgresql are correctly assigned without specifying the FQDN.*

Run the `pg_isready` *(remember the `host` is the service, not the pod)*:

```
root@test-shell-845c969686-h9gz2:/# pg_isready --host=postgresql --port=5432 --username=postgres --dbname=postgresql
postgresql:5432 - accepting connections
```

You can also test as a connection string:

The structure is `export my_conn='postgresql://user:password@FQDN/DATABASE'`

```
root@test-shell-845c969686-h9gz2:/# export my_conn='postgresql://postgres:postgres@postgresql/postgres'
root@test-shell-845c969686-h9gz2:/# pg_isready -d $my_conn
kneeling-scorpion-postgresql:5432 - accepting connections
```

Lastly, let's do the login connection again just like we did with the `postegresql-client` pod:

```
root@test-shell-845c969686-vh9zh:/# psql --host=postgresql --port=5432 --username=postgres --dbname=postgres  
Password for user postgres: 
psql (10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), server 11.6)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

IF: it works! Go to **Step 2**.

**IF NOT:**

- There may be **some problem with your PostgreSQL.**
- At this point I'd suggest you to try this tests again but with a clean database like the one from Helm Chart: `stable/postgresql`. [Documentation Here](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/postgresql). It's really easy to install and remove when needed.

### Step 2 - Narrowing down to the client:

At this point I assume your database connection is working properly.
So we must review a few things:

- If you can connect to the database from other pods I suggest you try to **deploy and run a instance of your APP from the Ubuntu POD** we used in Section B.

**If it still does not work, now you've narrowed to a problem inside your App.**

If you have any difficulty reproducing this solution, let me know in the comments.